# How do metatables work and what are they used for?

Tags: function, lua, programming-languages

I have this one question, about Lua metatables. I heard and looked them up, but I don't understand how to use them and for what.

Answer (score 11):

metatables are functions that are called under certain conditions.
Take the metatable index "__newindex" (two underscores), when you assign a function to this, that function will be called when ever you add a new index to a table, like;

```
table['wut'] = 'lol';
```

this is an example of a custom metatable using '__newindex'.

```
ATable = {}
setmetatable(ATable, {__newindex = function(t,k,v)
    print("Attention! Index \"" .. k .. "\" now contains the value \'" .. v .. "\' in " .. tostring(t));
end});

ATable["Hey"]="Dog";
```

the output:

> Attention! Index "Hey" now contains the value 'Dog' in table: 0022B000

metatables can also be used to describe how Tables should interact with other Tables, and different values.

This is a list of all the possible metatable indexes you can use

```
* __index(object, key) -- Index access "table[key]".
* __newindex(object, key, value) -- Index assignment "table[key] = value".
* __call(object, arg) -- called when Lua calls the object. arg is the argument passed.
* __len(object) -- The # length of operator.
* __concat(object1, object2) -- The .. concatination operator.
* __eq(object1, object2) -- The == equal to operator.
* __lt(object1, object2) -- The < less than operator.
* __le(object1, object2) -- The <= less than or equal to operator.
* __unm(object) -- The unary - operator.
* __add(object1, object2) -- The + addition operator.
* __sub(object1, object2) -- The - subtraction operator. Acts similar to __add.
* __mul(object1, object2) -- The * mulitplication operator. Acts similar to __add.
* __div(object1, object2) -- The / division operator. Acts similar to __add.
* __mod(object1, object2) -- The % modulus operator. Acts similar to __add.
* __tostring(object) -- Not a proper metamethod. Will return whatever you want it to return.
* __metatable -- if present, locks the metatable so getmetatable will return this instead of the metatable and setmetatable will error.
```

I hope this clears things up, if you need a few more examples,  [click here](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php/Metatables).

Comment: Thank you. =D And you can also use metatable to make your script look more advance?

Comment: Yeah, you could I guess.
Though I'd be more interested in something that does a more complex task.

Comment: Note that your example lies to the user. Unless you do `t[k] = v` somewhere in the `__newindex` metamethod, value will not get into the table.

Comment: "metatables are functions that are called under certain conditions", I don't think this is right. Metatables are _tables_ that can have one or more keys that point to functions that are called under certain conditions. The metamethod _name_ should be the key, the metamethod itself is the function that the key points to.

Answer (score 0):

They allow tables to be treated like other types such as string, functions, numbers etc.

Answer (score 0):

For a high level, entertaining read on the prototype pattern check out http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2008/10/universal-design-pattern.html. This may help you with the 'what'.